# Setting up SASS in ionic project

Tags: html, css, angularjs, sass, ionic-framework

Following is the command which I run to implement `SASS` in my project -

`ionic setup sass`

After node dependencies installed, I run - `ionic serve` command and tried changing - `$positive` with `teal` color code but it is not reflecting even if I reload the page in browser, though If I make change to $positive in `_variables.scss` after rerunning the command `ionic serve` it is showing the color.

I believe I only need to make change in `scss/ionic.app.scss` and it should automatically reflect the changes.

Let me know what I am missing here.

FYI - Following is the CSS in my `index.html`

```
<!-- compiled css output -->
<link href="css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Following is my gulpfile -

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var gutil = require('gulp-util');
var bower = require('bower');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var minifyCss = require('gulp-minify-css');
var rename = require('gulp-rename');
var sh = require('shelljs');

var paths = {
  sass: ['./scss/**/*.scss']
};

gulp.task('default', ['sass']);

gulp.task('sass', function(done) {
  gulp.src('./scss/ionic.app.scss')
    .pipe(sass())
    .on('error', sass.logError)
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./www/css/'))
    .pipe(minifyCss({
      keepSpecialComments: 0
    }))
    .pipe(rename({ extname: '.min.css' }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./www/css/'))
    .on('end', done);
});

gulp.task('watch', function() {
  gulp.watch(paths.sass, ['sass']);
});

gulp.task('install', ['git-check'], function() {
  return bower.commands.install()
    .on('log', function(data) {
      gutil.log('bower', gutil.colors.cyan(data.id), data.message);
    });
});

gulp.task('git-check', function(done) {
  if (!sh.which('git')) {
    console.log(
      '  ' + gutil.colors.red('Git is not installed.'),
      '\n  Git, the version control system, is required to download Ionic.',
      '\n  Download git here:', gutil.colors.cyan('http://git-scm.com/downloads') + '.',
      '\n  Once git is installed, run \'' + gutil.colors.cyan('gulp install') + '\' again.'
    );
    process.exit(1);
  }
  done();
});
```

**Edit 1-**

Screenshot 1-

[image: Root Directory]

Screenshot 2-

[image: WWW Folder Directory]

Screenshot 3 -

[image: scss Files]

My CSS in www folder -

[image: css]

Now you can in the 3rd screenshot I am having `_variables.scss` (at last) in which I am changing values, but it is not watching my changes. Once I did `ionic serve` it is showing the color change then.

Comment: Where are you defining the `$positive` variable that it's not working? If you're defining it in `scss/ionic.app.scss` before the `_variables.scss` file is imported its getting overwritten by `_variables.scss`.

Comment: @cimmanon your comment is  `irrelevant` and adds nothing `relevant` for a solution or guidance

Comment: @BrettDeWoody I added it in _variables.scss file ..but to view change I always need to do `ionic serve` command, I believe it should automatically reflect the changes..let me know what I am missing

Comment: Could you please post the directory/file structure of the files involved (`/www` folder, ionic lib, main html and css). From your last comment it seems you have 2 problems: where you do the modification (as BrettDeWoody said) and a path problem (it seems that gulp is not live-detecting the changes)

Comment: @arainone I added the screenshots, let me know if you help me with this please.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is add the `!default` flag to the colour you're overriding, that way it will overwrite the Ionic ones.

An example:

```
$light:                           #fff !default;
$stable:                          #f8f8f8 !default;
$positive:                        #387ef5 !default;
$calm:                            #11c1f3 !default;
$balanced:                        #33cd5f !default;
$energized:                       #ffc900 !default;
$assertive:                       #9D0000 !default;
$royal:                           #886aea !default;
$dark:                            #25272A !default;
$light-black:                     #303134 !default;
$gray:                            #939393 !default;
$light-gray:                      #BFBFBF !default;
$dark-brand:                      #0A9693 !default;
$danger-dark:                     #E0483E !default;
$facebook:                        #3B5998 !default;
```

PS: This configuration works with Ionic being imported after the declaration of these variables

Comment: I already did like this - `$positive:                        teal !default;`